# WithAadUserPromptAuthentication missing from Microsoft.Azure.Kusto.Data.NETStandard pacakge

Tags: .net-standard, azure-data-explorer

I am using the NuGet pacakge Microsoft.Azure.Kusto.Data.NETStandard (latest version 6.1.4 published yesterday). With the previous version I used to get the following error.

> Kusto Connection String Builder has some invalid or conflicting properties: specified 'AAD Username password' authentication method has incorrect properties set. ',
>   Please consult Kusto Connection String documentation at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/api/connection-strings/kusto

However, now the error changed and gives me further details as below.

> Kusto Connection String Builder has some invalid or conflicting properties: Specified 'AAD Username password' authentication method has some incorrect properties. Missing: [User ID,Password].. ',
>   Please consult Kusto Connection String documentation at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/api/connection-strings/kusto

Once I provided User ID and Password, it succeeded. (Which I don’t want to)

I also used `KustoConnectionStringBuilder` class from the Microsoft.Azure.Kusto.Data NuGet package (.NET Framework). This allows me to connect without passing user name and password by using `WithAadUserPromptAuthentication()`.

```cs
var kustoConnectionStringBuilder = new KustoConnectionStringBuilder(
    $"https://{serviceName}.kusto.windows.net")
.WithAadUserPromptAuthentication(authority);
```

Why is this method missing from .NetStandard package?

Answer (score 5):

I think that when they added the .NETStandard library, that functionality wasn't available. They do take requests for features on their [User Voice](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/915733-azure-data-explorer) site so I recommend that you request it there.

Edit: As noted over on the Tech Community thread that you started, the interactive AAD popup is not available in the .NET Standard version of the ADAL library, so Kusto couldn't take advantage of it. If this is an important feature, the best place to start is probably a feature request to ADAL though I'm not quite sure how they'd design that contract in .NET Standard.